# flask + nginx + uwsgi - Python application not found

Tags: python, nginx, flask, uwsgi

**cat /etc/nginx/sites-available/mywebsite**

```
server {
     listen              80;

    server_name         mywebsite;

    location /static {
        alias           /var/www/mywebsite/static;
    }

    location / {
        include         uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass      unix:/tmp/website.sock;
        uwsgi_param         UWSGI_PYHOME    /var/www/mywebsite/env;
        uwsgi_param         UWSGI_CHDIR     /var/www/mywebsite;
        uwsgi_param         UWSGI_MODULE    mywebsite;
        uwsgi_param         UWSGI_CALLABLE  mywebsite;
    }

    error_page          404     /404.html;

}
```

**cat /etc/uwsgi/apps-available/website.ini**

```
[uwsgi]
plugins=python
vhost=true
socket=/tmp/website.sock
```

**cat /var/www/mywebsite/mywebsite.py**

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return "It works!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

I'm running nginx, then uwsgi and has uWSGI Error 'Python application not found' in browser.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error, in the same configuration, and my problem was simply that the uwsgi service wasn't started. Restarting both nginx and uwsgi solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

UWSGI_CALLABLE must be 'app' (is the name of the function to call on the request)

Comment: I made a correction to the nginx config, as you say, but still the problem exists.
Here is my uwsgi log file [link](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=rZmnd65H) maybe the problem is in --enable-threads ?

Comment: i do not see requests logged in the file you linked, when you make a request to the nginx you should see something in uWSGI logs. If you do not see things check nginx logs, maybe it cannot connect to uWSGI

Comment: I restarted the uwsgi and now there are several errors in uwsgi log file. They are all the same :) "ImportError: No module named flask
" It is very strange, because I have installed Flask in my virtualenv.

Comment: is the virtualenv in /var/www/mywebsite/env and is it for the same python version used by uWSGI (as printed on startup) ?

Comment: It seems this is the source of all problems.
I have installed 2.7 version, but when I call the python interpreter I get version 2.6. Virtualenv is in /var/www/mywebsite/env.

Comment: I make rm /usr/local/bin/python 
and ln -s /usr/local/bin/python2.7 /usr/local/bin/python
but still have 2.6 when calling interpreter :(

Comment: Maybe I need to recreate my virtualenv after updating python.